# Correct syntax cURL --capath

Tags: curl

Using this command below and receiving code 60. Not recognize my repository using `--capath`:

```
  curl -X POST --capath /my-dir/cert/ 
  https://my-webservice.com:443/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/MyService 
  -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' 
  -H 'SOAPAction: ""' 
  --data-binary @/my-dir/cert/request.xml
```

Comment: How do you know your error 60 problem is because of a problem with --capath? (and please drop `-X POST`)

Comment: Hello Daniel, I executed an IWS process with this line command and I received error 60. All steps to create a file .pem are made. Thank you.